# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, record

Im testing my app with rspec with the next simple code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe CarsController do
    describe "GET 'new'" do
            it "should be successful" do
            visit new_user_car_path(:user_id=>"28")
            response.should be_success
            end
        end
    end
```

when I run it I got this message

```
Failure/Error: visit new_user_car_path(:user_id=>"28")
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find User with id=28
 # ./app/controllers/cars_controller.rb:3:in `new'
 # ./spec/controllers/tanking_logs_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't know whats happens with this, in my routes appears the new_user_car_path, look...

```
user_cars GET    /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)                               cars#index
                      POST   /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)                               cars#create
         new_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)                           cars#new
        edit_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/:id/edit(.:format)                      cars#edit
             user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)                           cars#show
                      PUT    /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)                           cars#update
                      DELETE /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)                           cars#destroy
```

and this is my routes.rb if it needs

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "static_pages#home"
match '/contact', :to=>'static_pages#contact'
match '/about', :to=>'static_pages#about'
devise_for :users
resources :gas_stations
   resources :users do
      resources :cars do
      #resources :tanking_logs
      end
   end
...
```

Comment: Just to rule out the easy stuff, have you tried restarting your server? Or do you have any routes in routes.rb that are `mounted`?

Comment: yes I restarted it many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)
```

Your path needs a `:user_id` param in order to work, and you're not providing one.

**EDIT** As per your comments, if you're using [Factory Girl Rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/) you can set up a factory to create users, and then do something like:

```
user = Factory.create :user
visit new_user_car_path(:id => user.id)
```

Else, you can manually create them:

```
user = User.create!(:name => "Joe", ...)
visit new_user_car_path(:id => user.id)
```

Comment: I tried this:

    visit new_user_car_path(:user_id=>"28")

but when I run my test it shows:

    Failure/Error: visit new_user_car_path(:user_id=>"28")
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find User with id=28

Comment: Did you randomly type in "28"? You would need a real user ID. Obviously it is doing a search for that User. You should have looked at your Cars controller and you would have seen it doing a search.

Comment: Are you sure that they exist in your test environment? The code you posted for your spec, assuming you did not leave out any `before()` calls, does not create any users. Test environments are wiped out before each run and are separate from your development environment where that user might exist.

Comment: ok I tried it and got an routes matches error

No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"cars", :id=>2}

Comment: Sorry I should have written `:user_id => user.id`, instead of `:id => user.id`. Your route needs a `user_id` param, not an `id` param.

Comment: if I have another problem, can I ask to you?

Comment: I would recommend creating a new question, which I or others would be more than happy to assist you in solving!